# What happened to the troops who were surrounding Winterfell?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* Season 2 Episode 10, Theon and his men in Winterfell were surrounded by the troops Robb sent. It seemed they don't stand a chance against the Robb's men. In the morning, Theon and his men shout battle cries before they confront the Northmen outside.

Suddenly, Theon was knocked down by one of his men. They carry unconscious Theon and try to sneak out evading the battle to their home.

And in the next cut, Bran, Rickon, Hodor and Osha get out of their hiding place. They see Winterfell is burning and its people are dead.

Where did all the troops go? They came to retake Winterfell. Winterfell was under siege by them. Then why no one but dead commoners and burning buildings when Bran and the others came out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Winterfell was surrounded by Bolton men, lead by Ramsay. Robb didn't send his troops because he was winning against Tywin and he didn't want to lose his position. So he had Roose Bolton send a raven to his bastard son Ramsay to root Theon out of Winterfell.

Ramsay, currently being the acting commander at the Dreadfort, took his men and surrounded Winterfell. He offered the Ironborn safe passage home if they give him Theon. They did, but Ramsay killed them anyway.

Winterfell was in ruins by that time, in the show it's not clear who did it and why - could be Ironborn or Boltons. They address it in several conversations (dying maester Luwin with kids, Roose Bolton with Walder Frey), but they have never made clear who did it. Since Boltons were repairing it after, my guess would be on Ironborn.

Ramsay then took Theon and his troops back to the Dreadfort, Boltons' home castle. That is why no troops stayed in Winterfell by that time. Osha, Hodor and the kids cleverly used this time to escape the castle.